# jQuery: Links in tree menu don't navigate, how to fix this?

Tags: jquery, tree, navigation, hyperlink

My tree menu is in an unordered list. The links in it however don't work, I think because the whole ul listens to the jquery script. I want the links to be navigationable, can anybody tell me how to do this?

jquery:

```
   $("#treeMenu li").toggle(

function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown()
    if ($(this).hasClass('contentContainer')) {
        $(this).removeClass('contentContainer').addClass('contentViewing');
    }
}, function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp()
    if ($(this).hasClass('contentViewing')) {
        $(this).removeClass('contentViewing').addClass('contentContainer');
    }
});
```

html:

```
<ul id="treeMenu">
    <li class="folder1"> folder1
        <ul style="display: none">
            <li class="contentContainer"><a href="http://www.google.com">1.1</a></li>

            <li class="contentContainer"><a href="http://www.google.com">1.2</a></li>

            <li class="contentContainer"><a href="http://www.google.com">1.3</a></li>

            <li class="contentContainer"><a href="http://www.google.com">1.4</a></li>

</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kukd2/)

Comment: Please put your code in your question as well; jsFiddle is an external site which could go down at anytime.

Comment: @mblase75 you're absolutely right, was planning on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [`.toggle` (event)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

> Since .toggle() internally uses a click handler to do its work, we must unbind click to remove a behavior attached with .toggle(), so other click handlers can be caught in the crossfire. The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event, so **links will not be followed** and buttons will not be clicked if .toggle() has been called on the element.

Looks like that's what's happening to you. You can add the click functionality back in with a couple of lines of jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});​
```

(This won't work in the fiddle, but it should work on your site.)

However, I don't like the way `.toggle` silently cancels out other click events, and it might surprise you again down the road, so I would replace your `.toggle` with a proper `.click` and use [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) instead:

```
$("#treeMenu li").click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    if ($(this).hasClass('contentContainer')) {
        $(this).removeClass('contentContainer').addClass('contentViewing');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('contentViewing')) {
        $(this).removeClass('contentViewing').addClass('contentContainer');
    };
});​
```

You might also use [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) inside the click handler to shorten your code, but I can't be sure of how you want classes to be added or removed based on your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kukd2/6/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Kukd2/3/
Check about slideToggle and toggleClass.

Answer (score 1):

Does work. Replace js in html file.

```
$("#treeMenu li").click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    if ($(this).hasClass('contentContainer')) {
        $(this).removeClass('contentContainer').addClass('contentViewing');     
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('contentViewing')) {
        $(this).removeClass('contentViewing').addClass('contentContainer');
    }
});​
```

---

JS that is wrong and wont allow you to set text links:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //Class 'contentContainer' refers to 'li' that has child with it.
    //By default the child ul of 'contentContainer' will be set to 'display:none'

        $("#treeMenu li").toggle(           

              function() { // START FIRST CLICK FUNCTION
                  $(this).children('ul').slideDown()
                  if ($(this).hasClass('contentContainer')) {   
                      $(this).removeClass('contentContainer').addClass('contentViewing');
                  }
              }, // END FIRST CLICK FUNCTION

              function() { // START SECOND CLICK FUNCTION
                  $(this).children('ul').slideUp()

                  if ($(this).hasClass('contentViewing')) {
                      $(this).removeClass('contentViewing').addClass('contentContainer');
                  }
                    } // END SECOND CLICK FUNCTIOn
                ); // END TOGGLE FUNCTION 

    }); // END DOCUMENT READY

</script>
```

---

Like this site or JQuery tree menu, has downloadable ZIP. 
http://mediamilan.com/how-to-create-simple-tree-structure-menu-using-jquery-and-css/

*CHANGE the JS in the page below head,because it's wrong.
This allows you to set href or link.